# Can python date/time/datetime objects have a boolean value of False?

Tags: python, python-datetime, truthiness

I ran into some code recently that was checking datetime objects and figured it could be cleaned up a little:

```py
# original
if (datetime1 and (datetime2 is None)):
  do_things()

# slightly cleaner version
if (datetime1 and not datetime2):
  do_things()
```

But I realized that these two statements are not quite equal IF there is a valid datetime object that evaluates as False. For example:

```py
if not '':
  print('beep')
else:
  print('boop')
# output: beep

if '' is None:
  print('beep')
else:
  print('boop')
# output: boop
```

Upon looking for information about the boolean value of datetime/time/date objects in Python, I came up empty. Does anyone know how Python handles this? And if I run into a similar problem with a different object type, is there a reliable way to check when its boolean value is true or false?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, but why even change the code? To me, the first version is actually *"cleaner"* (or at least clea**r**er)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo there really wasn't too much of a reason to change the code besides the matter of personal preference (fwiw the code is mine)-- my question was less "how do I approach this situation" and more "are these two code snippets equivalent"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the class implements a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method that customizes it, all class instances are truthy by default. If `__bool__()` is defined, it's used. If not, the default `object.__bool__()` calls `__len__()`; if it returns non-zero, the object is truthy.

The `datetime.datetime` class doesn't have such either method, so all datetime objects are truthy. So your transformation is valid.

This is documented at [`object.__bool__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return False or True. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

Comment: I went to write a helper function to test if a class implements this and got some odd results. The function was equivalent to `lambda x: '__bool__' in dir(type(x))` and it did return True for an integer, but returned False for a string. I also tried calling `__bool__()` on objects of both types and found the same.

Comment: @Sam I think you can avoid the `dir()` and string find by changing your lambda to `lambda x: getattr(x, '__bool__', None) is not None`

Comment: My answer was incomplete. It also tries using `__len__()`. @SamZuk